# CAS Authentication with Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii, cas

I'm facing some troubles trying to implement `CAS` Authentication with `Yii` framework. I [downloaded the client classes](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS) and everything is working when I'm not using any framework, but when I try to integrate with `Yii` validation seems to not be working at all.

Can Anyone please describe the process to successfuly make a CAS validation with yii.

I put the clients files under /myapp/protected/vendor directory, then I put the following lines at the begining of the controller

```
Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
require_once('CAS/CAS.php');
```

Then I created the method for use my CAS Classes

```
public function casValidation()
{
   phpCAS::client(CAS_VERSION_2_0, $server, $port, "/cas",false);
   phpCAS::setNoCasServerValidation();
   phpCAS::forceAuthentication();

   if(isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) 
   {
      phpCAS::logout();
   }
}
```

And Finally I try to validate from my index action

```
public function actionIndex()
{
   $this->casValidation();
   $this->render('index');
}
```

But in the web browser shows the following error

> PHP warning
>
> include(CAS_Client.php) [function.include]: failed to open >stream: No such file or directory
>
> C:\app\vertrigo\Vertrigophp52\www\testyii\framework\YiiBase.php(427)

Am I Missing something? What should I do to make things work?

Comment: _"seems to not be working at all"_ is a vague allegation and _"Can Anyone please describe the process to successfuly make a CAS validation with yii"_ is a vague expectation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working, turns out that I had made a couple of mistakes.

First of all I should not have been using require statement. The reason for this is that Yii alredy take care of loading the classes via the import method as shown below.

```
Yii::import('application.vendor.CAS.*')
```

Second thing I had a typo on this import, I had

```
/* This is wrong */
Yii::import('application.vendors.CAS.*')
```

instead of

```
/* This is correct */
Yii::import('application.vendor.CAS.*')
```

So Yii was looking for the vendors directory which does not exist.

And finally, to successfully use the import method the file containing your class has to have the same name. So if you have a class name user you have to name your file user.php in order to Yii can load it successfully.